# /usr/ldbin/resetpw varient for Linux

Tags: linux, hp-ux

I've got a application that makes a shell call out to the HPUX resetpw command. It doesn't exist in Linux. Is there another command with similar functionality I could reference from my code?

Comment: Is not really clear for me what resetpw does on HPUX (and I don't have a UX machine near now), can you tell us a bit more?

Comment: It does some sort of password reset.  It's in /usr/ldbin and apparently it calls /usr/ldbin/enableuser as part of it's operation.

Comment: what about "chpasswd" ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up avoiding the entire thing by using AD authentication.

Answer (score 1):

If 'resetpw' does what it sounds like, you probably want the 'passwd' command on linux.

Here are a few other commands that are useful for user account administration.
http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-users-tools.html